# Flattening a dict

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following array of dicts (there's only one dict):

```
[{
    'RuntimeInMinutes': '21',
    'EpisodeNumber': '21',
    'Genres': ['Animation'],
    'ReleaseDate': '2005-02-05',
    'LanguageOfMetadata': 'EN',
    'Languages': [{
        '_Key': 'CC',
        'Value': ['en']
    }, {
        '_Key': 'Primary',
        'Value': ['EN']
    }],
    'Products': [{
        'URL': 'http://www.hulu.com/watch/217566',
        'Rating': 'TV-Y',
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'SUBSCRIPTION': '0.00',
        '_Key': 'US'
    }, {
        'URL': 'http://www.hulu.com/d/217566',
        'Rating': 'TV-Y',
        'Currency': 'USD',
        'SUBSCRIPTION': '0.00',
        '_Key': 'DE'
    }],
    'ReleaseYear': '2005',
    'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries',
    'Type': 'TVEpisode',
    'Studio': '4K Media'
}]
```

I would like to flatten the dict as follows:

```
[{
    'RuntimeInMinutes': '21',
    'EpisodeNumber': '21',
    'Genres': ['Animation'],
    'ReleaseDate': '2005-02-05',
    'LanguageOfMetadata': 'EN',
    'Languages._Key': ['CC', 'Primary'],
    'Languages.Value': ['en', 'EN'],
    'Products.URL': ['http://www.hulu.com/watch/217566', 'http://www.hulu.com/d/217566'],
    'Products.Rating': ['TV-Y', 'TV-Y'],
    'Products.Currency': ['USD', 'USD'],
    'Products.SUBSCRIPTION': ['0.00', '0.00'],
    'Products._Key': ['US', 'DE'],
    'ReleaseYear': '2005',
    'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries',
    'Type': 'TVEpisode',
    'Studio': '4K Media'
}]
```

In other words, anytime a dict is encountered, it need to convert to either a string, number, or list.

What I currently have is something along the lines of the following, which uses a while loop to iterate through all the subpaths of the json.

```
    while True:

        for key in copy(keys):

            val = get_sub_object_from_path(obj, key)

            if isinstance(val, dict):
                FLAT_OBJ[key.replace('/', '.')] = val
            else:
                keys.extend(os.path.join(key, _nextkey) for _nextkey in val.keys())
            keys.remove(key)

        if (not keys) or (n > 5):
            break
        else:
            n += 1
            continue
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import defaultdict
_d = [{'RuntimeInMinutes': '21', 'EpisodeNumber': '21', 'Genres': ['Animation'], 'ReleaseDate': '2005-02-05', 'LanguageOfMetadata': 'EN', 'Languages': [{'_Key': 'CC', 'Value': ['en']}, {'_Key': 'Primary', 'Value': ['EN']}], 'Products': [{'URL': 'http://www.hulu.com/watch/217566', 'Rating': 'TV-Y', 'Currency': 'USD', 'SUBSCRIPTION': '0.00', '_Key': 'US'}, {'URL': 'http://www.hulu.com/d/217566', 'Rating': 'TV-Y', 'Currency': 'USD', 'SUBSCRIPTION': '0.00', '_Key': 'DE'}], 'ReleaseYear': '2005', 'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries', 'Type': 'TVEpisode', 'Studio': '4K Media'}]

def get_vals(d, _path = []):
  for a, b in getattr(d, 'items', lambda :{})():
    if isinstance(b, list) and all(isinstance(i, dict) or isinstance(i, list) for i in b):
       for c in b:
         yield from get_vals(c, _path+[a])
    elif isinstance(b, dict):
       yield from get_vals(b, _path+[a])
    else:
       yield ['.'.join(_path+[a]), b]

results = [i for b in _d for i in get_vals(b)]
_c = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in results:
  _c[a].append(b)

result = [{a:list(b) if len(b) > 1 else b[0] for a, b in _c.items()}]
import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "RuntimeInMinutes": "21",
    "EpisodeNumber": "21",
    "Genres": [
        "Animation"
    ],
    "ReleaseDate": "2005-02-05",
    "LanguageOfMetadata": "EN",
    "Languages._Key": [
        "CC",
        "Primary"
    ],
    "Languages.Value": [
        [
            "en"
        ],
        [
            "EN"
        ]
    ],
    "Products.URL": [
        "http://www.hulu.com/watch/217566",
        "http://www.hulu.com/d/217566"
    ],
    "Products.Rating": [
        "TV-Y",
        "TV-Y"
    ],
    "Products.Currency": [
        "USD",
        "USD"
    ],
    "Products.SUBSCRIPTION": [
        "0.00",
        "0.00"
    ],
    "Products._Key": [
        "US",
        "DE"
    ],
    "ReleaseYear": "2005",
    "TVSeriesID": "5638#TVSeries",
    "Type": "TVEpisode",
    "Studio": "4K Media"
  }
]
```

Edit: wrapping solution in outer function:

```
def flatten_obj(data):
  def get_vals(d, _path = []):
    for a, b in getattr(d, 'items', lambda :{})():
      if isinstance(b, list) and all(isinstance(i, dict) or isinstance(i, list) for i in b):
        for c in b:
          yield from get_vals(c, _path+[a])
      elif isinstance(b, dict):
        yield from get_vals(b, _path+[a])
      else:
        yield ['.'.join(_path+[a]), b]
  results = [i for b in data for i in get_vals(b)]
  _c = defaultdict(list)
  for a, b in results:
     _c[a].append(b)
  return [{a:list(b) if len(b) > 1 else b[0] for a, b in _c.items()}]
```

Comment: thanks -- it needs to append to the list though, here it seems to be taking the last string value. For example: `'Products._Key': ['US', 'DE'],`.

Comment: 1234 -- wow that's pretty awesome. Thanks, this recursion is so difficult for me and it seems like a synch for u.

Comment: @DavidL Utilizing a generator i.e `yield` and `yield from` constructs makes recursion much easier, as it better enables you to think about the data, rather than how to store the accumulated results (the generator function points to the values in memory instead)

Comment: this may be a silly question, but how would I put the above into a function called "flatten_obj"? It works when running from the command line but when I put it into a method call it seems to return empty with the yield statement.

Comment: thanks, I had something similar, but that still gives me `>>> flatten_obj(d)
[{}]`.

Comment: @Ajax1234 How did you get the code to print it this way?

Comment: @Ajax1234 it seems like unless the `d` is defined within the function, it is returning an empty dict (perhaps overwriting it when successively called).

Comment: @U9-Forward By utilizing `json`:`json.dumps(result, indent=4)`

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thaanks.

Comment: @DavidL Make sure you define the structure `d` with a different variable name outside `flatten_obj`. `d` is a variable name within the nested function `get_vals`

Comment: @DavidL I am able to get it to work when I store the structure as `__d`, and call the function as `flatten_obj(__d)`

Comment: @Ajax1234 awesome, yup me too. Thank you for the edits!

Comment: @DavidL No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

This now appears to be fixed:

> As @panda-34 correctly points out (+1), the currently accepted
>   solution loses data, specifically `Genres` and `Languages.Value` when
>   you run the posted code.

Unfortunately, @panda-34's code modifies `Genres`:

```
'Genres': 'Animation',
```

rather than leaving it alone as in the OP's example:

```
'Genres': ['Animation'],
```

Below's my solution which attacks the problem a different way.  None of the keys in the original data contains a dictionary as a value, only non-containers or lists (e.g. lists of dictionaries).  So a primary a list of dictionaries will becomes a dictionary of lists (or just a plain dictionary if there's only one dictionary in the list.)  Once we've done that, then any value that's now a dictionary is expanded back into the original data structure:

```
def flatten(container):
    # A list of dictionaries becomes a dictionary of lists (unless only one dictionary in list)
    if isinstance(container, list) and all(isinstance(element, dict) for element in container):
        new_dictionary = {}

        first, *rest = container

        for key, value in first.items():
            new_dictionary[key] = [flatten(value)] if rest else flatten(value)

        for dictionary in rest:
            for key, value in dictionary.items():
                new_dictionary[key].append(value)

        container = new_dictionary

    # Any dictionary value that's a dictionary is expanded into original dictionary
    if isinstance(container, dict):
        new_dictionary = {}

        for key, value in container.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
                    new_dictionary[key + "." + sub_key] = sub_value
            else:
                new_dictionary[key] = value

        container = new_dictionary

    return container
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    "RuntimeInMinutes": "21",
    "EpisodeNumber": "21",
    "Genres": [
        "Animation"
    ],
    "ReleaseDate": "2005-02-05",
    "LanguageOfMetadata": "EN",
    "Languages._Key": [
        "CC",
        "Primary"
    ],
    "Languages.Value": [
        [
            "en"
        ],
        [
            "EN"
        ]
    ],
    "Products.URL": [
        "http://www.hulu.com/watch/217566",
        "http://www.hulu.com/d/217566"
    ],
    "Products.Rating": [
        "TV-Y",
        "TV-Y"
    ],
    "Products.Currency": [
        "USD",
        "USD"
    ],
    "Products.SUBSCRIPTION": [
        "0.00",
        "0.00"
    ],
    "Products._Key": [
        "US",
        "DE"
    ],
    "ReleaseYear": "2005",
    "TVSeriesID": "5638#TVSeries",
    "Type": "TVEpisode",
    "Studio": "4K Media"
}
```

But this solution introduces a new apparent inconsistency:

```
'Languages.Value': ['en', 'EN'],
```

vs.

```
"Languages.Value": [["en"], ["EN"]],
```

However, I believe this is tied up with the `Genres` inconsistency mentioned earlier and the OP needs to define a consistent resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax1234's answer loses values of 'Genres' and 'Languages.Value'
Here's a bit more generic version:

```
def flatten_obj(data):
    def flatten_item(item, keys):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for v in item:
                yield from flatten_item(v, keys)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            for k, v in item.items():
                yield from flatten_item(v, keys+[k])
        else:
            yield '.'.join(keys), item

    res = []
    for item in data:
        res_item = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in flatten_item(item, []):
            res_item[k].append(v)
        res.append({k: (v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]) for k, v in res_item.items()})
    return res
```

P.S. "Genres" value is also flattened. It is either an inconsistency in the OP requirements or a separate problem which is not addressed in this answer.